# Exercise in Exorcism: Exchange Rates

Tags: python

I have to create a script in Python that converts money while also adding in an exchange fee. Here are the exact instructions:

> Create the exchangeable_value() function, taking budget,
> exchange_rate, spread, and denomination.
>
> Parameter spread is the percentage taken as an exchange fee, written
> as an integer. It needs to be converted to decimal by dividing it by
> 100. If 1.00 EUR == 1.20 USD and the spread is 10, the actual exchange rate will be: 1.00 EUR == 1.32 USD because 10% of 1.20 is 0.12, and
> this additional fee is added to the exchange.
>
> This function should return the maximum value of the new currency
> after calculating the exchange rate plus the spread. Remember that the
> currency denomination is a whole number and cannot be sub-divided.
>
> Note: Returned value should be int type.

That said, here's the code I came up with:

```
def exchangeable_value(budget, exchange_rate, spread, denomination):
    new_exchange_rate = exchange_rate * ((spread/100)+1)
    x = budget/new_exchange_rate
    return x//denomination
```

For the sake of being thorough, here are the test inputs and the outputs I'm getting:

```
(100000, 10.61, 10, 1): 8568 (correct)

(1500, 0.84, 25, 40): 35.0, should be 1400

(470000, 1050, 30, 10000000000): 0 (correct)

(470000, 0.00000009, 30, 700): 5,738,705,738.0, should be 4,017,094,016,600

(425.33, 0.0009, 30, 700): 519.0, should be 363,300
```

FWIW, the answer is available to me, I just don't understand why my code isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with:

```
return x//denomination
```

You should not just divide the amount by the denomination, as that will return how many units you need of a denomination.

Instead you should return a multiple of `denomination` to cover for the desired value. So correct to:

```
return (x//denomination)*denomination
```

Comment: Agh, I knew I was close.

Thank you very much!